# Merge step using binary search in merge sort algorithm

Tags: c++, mergesort

We have to convert serial code into parallel code, according to my research it is not possible to paralllelize the merge-step if one uses the standard method. One has to use a method which is presented in this lecture note (Algorithm 3) [lecture notes](https://stanford.edu/%7Erezab/classes/cme323/S16/notes/Lecture03/cme323_lec3.pdf) . Before I tried to use parallelization I tried to implement the code and see if it runs in serial.

However the verification yields failed, i.e. the array that should be sorted is not sorted. My main problem is to find the rank of an element in an array where multiple elements could be. The algorithm is described in the lecture note but I start to believe that it maybe not works if there are multiple instances of the same number.

Lets say we have the two Arrays

```
A=[0_1,0_2,2_1,5_1,5_2,8_1] and B=[0_3,2_2,2_3,5_3,6_1,6_2]
```

In the end we want to have

```
C=[0_1,0_2,0_3,2_1,2_2,2_3,5_1,5_2,5_3,6_1,6_2,8_1]
```

We want to do this by calculate the rank,

i.e.

```
rank_C(x)=rank_B(x)+rank_A(x)
```

I know the results rank_C(x)

but I dont know the algorithm that finds rank_A(x) and rank_B(x) respectively in logarithmic time with binary search.

We should have:

```
0=rank_C(0_1)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
1=rank_C(0_2)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
2=rank_C(0_3)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
3=rank_C(2_1)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
4=rank_C(2_2)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
5=rank_C(2_3)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
6=rank_C(5_1)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
7=rank_C(5_2)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
8=rank_C(5_3)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
9=rank_C(6_1)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
10=rank_C(6_2)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
11=rank_C(8_6)=rank_A("")+rank_B("")
```

or alternatively a solution for the problem where the left side is incremendet by 1.

I dont even know how the solutions should look like for the function rank_A(x), because what if the list A has for example the smallest and the biggest element?

If we want to assign a 0 for the smallest element that means that both rankA(smallest)+rankB(smalles)=0+0. This implies however that the range of our value is limited by 10 in this case. So we have to assign a 1 for the smallest element and a 12 to the biggest element, but how do we do that? It seems to be inpossible, because if we want to get 1 from our addition then one of the function has to yield 0, this other function therefore can have a maximum value of 5. This means that in total we could only get a maximal value 11, this however cannot be, because we wanted to assign 12 to our biggest element.

I have tried nonetheless:

The relevant part is the merge step

old code - working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <omp.h>
// Constants.h
#if !defined(MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H)
#define MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H 1



#endif


/**
  * helper routine: check if array is sorted correctly
  */
bool isSorted(int ref[], int data[], const size_t size){
    std::sort(ref, ref + size);
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx){
        if (ref[idx] != data[idx]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
  * sequential merge step (straight-forward implementation)
  */
void MsMergeSequential(int *out, int *in, long begin1, long end1, long begin2, long end2, long outBegin) {
    long left = begin1;
    long right = begin2;
    long idx = outBegin;
    
    while (left < end1 && right < end2) {
        if (in[left] <= in[right]) {
            out[idx] = in[left];    
            left++;
        } else {
            out[idx] = in[right];
            right++;
        }
        idx++;
        }
    
    while (left < end1) {
        out[idx] = in[left];
        left++, idx++;
    }
    while (right < end2) {
        out[idx] = in[right];
        right++, idx++;
    }
}
bool myfunc (long i , long j){return (i<j);}
/**
  * sequential MergeSort
  */
void MsSequential(int *array, int *tmp, bool inplace, long begin, long end) {
  if (begin < (end - 1)) {
           long half =(begin+end) / 2;


            
         {
           

             MsSequential(array, tmp, !inplace, begin, half);

             MsSequential(array, tmp, !inplace, half, end);
              }
 if (inplace){
            MsMergeSequential(array, tmp, begin, half, half, end, begin);
 } else {
            MsMergeSequential(tmp, array, begin, half, half, end, begin);
 }
        
    } else if (!inplace) {

        tmp[begin] = array[begin];
    }
}

/**
  * Serial MergeSort
  */
void MsSerial(int *array, int *tmp, const size_t size) {

    MsSequential(array, tmp, true, 0, size);
}

/**

/**
  * @brief program entry point
  */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // variables to measure the elapsed time
    struct timeval t1, t2;
    double etime;

    // expect one command line arguments: array size
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: MergeSort.exe <array size> \n");
        printf("\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else {
        const size_t stSize = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        int *data = (int*) malloc(stSize * sizeof(int));
        int *tmp = (int*) malloc(stSize * sizeof(int));     
        int *ref = (int*) malloc(stSize * sizeof(int));
        printf("Initialization...\n");

        srand(95);

        
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < stSize; ++idx){
            data[idx] = (int) (stSize * (double(rand()) / RAND_MAX));
        }
        std::copy(data, data + stSize, ref);

        double dSize = (stSize * sizeof(int)) / 1024 / 1024;
        printf("Sorting %zu elements of type int (%f MiB)...\n", stSize, dSize);

        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
        
        {
        
        {
        MsSerial(data, tmp, stSize);
        }
        }
        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
        etime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000;
        etime = etime / 1000;

        printf("done, took %f sec. Verification...", etime);
        if (isSorted(ref, data, stSize)) {
            printf(" successful.\n");
        }
        else {
            printf(" FAILED.\n");
        }

        free(data);
        //delete[] data;
        free(tmp);
        //delete[] tmp;
        free(ref);
        //delete[] ref;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

new code - does not work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <omp.h>
// Constants.h
#if !defined(MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H)
#define MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H 1



#endif


int mybinarysearchleftmost(int *in,int n, int value){
  

    int R=n;
    int L=0;
    while(R-L>1){
        int middle = (R+L)/2;
    
        if(in[middle]==value){while(in[middle]==value && middle > 0){middle=middle-1;}if(middle==0){return -1;} else {return (middle+1);}}
        if(in[middle]<value){L=middle+1;}
        if(in[middle]>value){R=middle-1;}
    }
    if(in[R]<value)
    {
    return R;}
    else{
      
      if(in[L]>= value && L==0){return -1;}
else return L;}


}


/**
  * helper routine: check if array is sorted correctly
  */
bool isSorted(int ref[], int data[], const size_t size){
    std::sort(ref, ref + size);
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx){
        if (ref[idx] != data[idx]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
  * sequential merge step (straight-forward implementation)
  */
void MsMergeSequential(int *out, int *in, long begin1, long end1, long begin2, long end2, long outBegin) {
    
    
    int helperarray[(end2-begin1)];
    
    for(int i=0;i<(end2-begin1);i++){
        helperarray[i]=0;
    }
    int helperarray2[(end2-begin1)];
    
    for(int i=0;i<(end2-begin1);i++){
        helperarray2[i]=0;
    }
    int array1[end1-begin1];
    
    for(int i=0;i<(end1-begin1);i++){
      array1[i]=in[begin1+i];
    }
    printf("[");
for(int i=0;i<(end1-begin1);i++){printf("%u,",array1[i]);}
printf("]\n");
    int array2[end2-begin2];
    
    for(int i=0;i<(end1-begin1);i++){
      array2[i]=in[begin2+i];
    }
    printf("[");
for(int i=0;i<(end2-begin2);i++){printf("%u,",array2[i]);}
printf("]\n");

    for(int i = 0;i<(end2-begin2);i++){
  helperarray[i+mybinarysearchleftmost(array1,(end2-begin2),array2[i])]=array2[i];
  helperarray2[i+mybinarysearchleftmost(array1,(end2-begin2),array2[i])]=1;
 }
 int counter=0;
 for(int i = 0;i<(end2-begin1);i++){
  if(helperarray2[i]==0){helperarray[i]=array1[counter];counter++;}
 }
 for(int i=0;i<(end2-begin1);i++){
   out[begin1+i]=helperarray[i];
}

  
}
bool myfunc (long i , long j){return (i<j);}
/**
  * sequential MergeSort
  */
void MsSequential(int *array, int *tmp, bool inplace, long begin, long end) {
  if (begin < (end - 1)) {
           long half =(begin+end) / 2;


            
         {
           

             MsSequential(array, tmp, !inplace, begin, half);

             MsSequential(array, tmp, !inplace, half, end);
              }
 if (inplace){
            MsMergeSequential(array, tmp, begin, half, half, end, begin);
 } else {
            MsMergeSequential(tmp, array, begin, half, half, end, begin);
 }
        
    } else if (!inplace) {

        tmp[begin] = array[begin];
    }
}

/**
  * Serial MergeSort
  */
void MsSerial(int *array, int *tmp, const size_t size) {

    MsSequential(array, tmp, true, 0, size);
}

/**

/**
  * @brief program entry point
  */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // variables to measure the elapsed time
    struct timeval t1, t2;
    double etime;

    // expect one command line arguments: array size
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: MergeSort.exe <array size> \n");
        printf("\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else {
        const size_t stSize = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        int *data = (int*) malloc(stSize * sizeof(int));
        int *tmp = (int*) malloc(stSize * sizeof(int));     
        int *ref = (int*) malloc(stSize * sizeof(int));
        printf("Initialization...\n");

        srand(95);

        
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < stSize; ++idx){
            data[idx] = (int) (stSize * (double(rand()) / RAND_MAX));
        }
        std::copy(data, data + stSize, ref);

        double dSize = (stSize * sizeof(int)) / 1024 / 1024;
        printf("Sorting %zu elements of type int (%f MiB)...\n", stSize, dSize);

        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
        
        {
        
        {
        MsSerial(data, tmp, stSize);
        }
        }
        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
        etime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000;
        etime = etime / 1000;

        printf("done, took %f sec. Verification...", etime);
        if (isSorted(ref, data, stSize)) {
            printf(" successful.\n");
        }
        else {
            printf(" FAILED.\n");
        }

        free(data);
        //delete[] data;
        free(tmp);
        //delete[] tmp;
        free(ref);
        //delete[] ref;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The last array looks like this, something went wrong in the mergestep:

```
[9,4,1,1,1,1,10967,1,10,11,1,1,10967,10967,1,17,10967,1,0,681153680,]
```

---

I have finaly solved the problem with the help of the answers: this is now the new and working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <omp.h>
// Constants.h
#if !defined(MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H)
#define MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H 1



#endif


//Takes a sorted list of size n and a value, puts the value in one of n+1 possible positions, if value is same to an element of the list take the position after the last occurence of the same element

int binarysearchfindlowerrank(int *in,int n,int value){


    int L=0;
    int R=n;
    while(R-L>1){
        int middle = (R+L)/2;

        if(in[middle]==value){while(in[middle]==value&&middle>0){middle=middle-1;}return middle+1;}
        if(in[middle]<value){L=middle;}
        if(in[middle]>value){R=middle;}
    }

    if(L==0&&in[L]>value){return 0;}
    if(R==n && in[R-1]< value){return n;}
    if(R==n&& in[R-1]>=value){return R-1;}
    if(in[R]<value){return R+1;}
    if(in[L]<value){return R;}
    return L;
}

//Takes a sorted list of size n and a value, puts the value in one of n+1 possible positions, if value is same to an element of the list take the position before the first occurence of the same element



int binarysearchfinduperrank(int *in,int n,int value){

    int L=0;
    int R=n;
    while(R-L>1){

        int middle = (R+L)/2;

        if(in[middle]==value){
            while(in[middle]==value&&middle<n)
            {middle=middle+1;}
            return middle;}
        if(in[middle]<value){L=middle;}
        if(in[middle]>value){R=middle;}
    }

    if(L==0&&in[L]>value){return 0;}
    if(R==n && in[R-1]<= value){return n;}
    if(R==n&& in[R-1]>value){return R-1;}
    if(in[R]<=value){return R+1;}
    if(in[L]<=value){return R;}
    return L;;
}

/**
  * helper routine: check if array is sorted correctly
  */
bool isSorted(int ref[], int data[], const size_t size){
    std::sort(ref, ref + size);
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx){
        if (ref[idx] != data[idx]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
  * sequential merge step (straight-forward implementation)
  */
void MsMergeSequential(int *out, int *in, long begin1, long end1, long begin2, long end2, long outBegin) {

    if(begin1==end2){out[begin1]=in[begin1];}

    else{
    long left = begin1;
    long right = begin2;
    long idx = outBegin;
    int array1[end1-begin1];
    int array2[end2-begin2];
    int merged[end2-begin1];
    for(int i=0;i<(end1-begin1);i++){
        array1[i]=in[begin1+i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<(end2-begin2);i++){
        array2[i]=in[begin2+i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<(end2-begin2);i++){
        merged[i+binarysearchfindlowerrank(array1,(end1-begin1),array2[i])]=array2[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<(end1-begin1);i++){
        merged[i+binarysearchfinduperrank(array2,(end2-begin2),array1[i])]=array1[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<(end2-begin1);i++){
        out[begin1+i]=merged[i];
    }
    }
}
bool myfunc (long i , long j){return (i<j);}
/**
  * sequential MergeSort
  */
void MsSequential(int *array, int *tmp, bool inplace, long begin, long end) {
  if (begin < (end - 1)) {
           long half =(begin+end) / 2;



         {


             MsSequential(array, tmp, !inplace, begin, half);

             MsSequential(array, tmp, !inplace, half, end);
              }
 if (inplace){
            MsMergeSequential(array, tmp, begin, half, half, end, begin);
 } else {
            MsMergeSequential(tmp, array, begin, half, half, end, begin);
 }

    } else if (!inplace) {

        tmp[begin] = array[begin];
    }
}

/**
  * Serial MergeSort
  */
void MsSerial(int *array, int *tmp, const size_t size) {

    MsSequential(array, tmp, true, 0, size);
}

/**

/**
  * @brief program entry point
  */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // variables to measure the elapsed time
    struct timeval t1, t2;
    double etime;

    // expect one command line arguments: array size
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: MergeSort.exe <array size> \n");
        printf("\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else {
        const size_t stSize = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        int *data = (int*) malloc(stSize * sizeof(int));
        int *tmp = (int*) malloc(stSize * sizeof(int));
        int *ref = (int*) malloc(stSize * sizeof(int));
        printf("Initialization...\n");

        srand(95);


        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < stSize; ++idx){
            data[idx] = (int) (stSize * (double(rand()) / RAND_MAX));
        }
        std::copy(data, data + stSize, ref);

        double dSize = (stSize * sizeof(int)) / 1024 / 1024;
        printf("Sorting %zu elements of type int (%f MiB)...\n", stSize, dSize);

        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

        {

        {
        MsSerial(data, tmp, stSize);
        }
        }
        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
        etime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000;
        etime = etime / 1000;

        printf("done, took %f sec. Verification...", etime);
        if (isSorted(ref, data, stSize)) {
            printf(" successful.\n");
        }
        else {
            printf(" FAILED.\n");
        }

        free(data);
        //delete[] data;
        free(tmp);
        //delete[] tmp;
        free(ref);
        //delete[] ref;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Console Output:

```
Initialization...
Sorting 100 elements of type int (0.000000 MiB)...
done, took 0.000000 sec. Verification... successful.
```

Comment: This is a weird mixture of C and C++.

Comment: The new merge doesn't do anything except calculating some numbers and then immediately throwing them away. There is no merge going on. The algorithm you reference calculates some positions in the array, but you need to put something at these positions.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I updated the code according to your suggestions, there is no memory core dump or endless loop or other weird behaviour but it still does not work because it is incorrect, what is wrong now?

Comment: (1) Your `MsMergeSequential` doesn't seem to do what the algorithm desctiption says, namely, `rank_M(a) = rank_A(a) + rank_B(a).` Where's this `+` in your code? (2) You never pass any *value* stored in the array to `mybinarysearchrightmost`. You only ever pass *indices*. This is wrong, binary search doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So we have to assign a 1 for the smallest element and a 12 to the biggest element, but how do we do that? It seems to be inpossible, because if we want to get 1 from our addition then one of the function has to yield 0, this other function therefore can have a maximum value of 5.

No you don't. You want to assign 0 to the smallest element and 11 to the largest.

In your example, the range of results from the rank functions is [0, 6], not [0, 5]. When you are trying to place an value larger than all the elements you are probing, it's correct index is one past the end of the array. You don't access that position in the input.

expressed using functions in C++'s `<algorithm>` header, although you should probably write `lower_bound` yourself

```
size_t rank(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Value value) {
    auto probe = std::lower_bound(first, last, value);
    return std::distance(first, probe);
}

void merge(RandomAccessIterator1 first1, RandomAccessIterator1 last1, RandomAccessIterator2 first2, RandomAccessIterator2 last2, OutputIterator d_first) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::distance(first1, last1); ++i) {
        auto value = first1[i];
        auto j = rank(first2, last2, value);
        d_first[i + j] = value;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::distance(first2, last2); ++i) {
        auto value = first2[i];
        auto j = rank(first1, last1, value);
        d_first[i + j] = value;
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't handle equivalent elements correctly. For that, you have to decide how to tie break them. A simple choice is to say that equivalent elements of A precede those of B. To handle that, we can split `rank` into two

```
size_t rank_A(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Value value) {
    auto probe = std::lower_bound(first, last, value); // find the first element equal or greater
    return std::distance(first, probe);
}

size_t rank_B(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Value value) {
    auto probe = std::upper_bound(first, last, value); // find the first element strictly greater
    return std::distance(first, probe);
}

void merge(RandomAccessIterator1 first1, RandomAccessIterator1 last1, RandomAccessIterator2 first2, RandomAccessIterator2 last2, OutputIterator d_first) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::distance(first1, last1); ++i) {
        auto value = first1[i];
        auto j = rank_A(first2, last2, value);
        d_first[i + j] = value;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::distance(first2, last2); ++i) {
        auto value = first2[i];
        auto j = rank_B(first1, last1, value);
        d_first[i + j] = value;
    }
}
```

This can still be parallelised in the same way as before.

Comment: can you give me an advice how to learn c++ on such a level like yours? I.e. if you see my code what should I learn to become better?

Comment: @New2Math The *most* beneficial skill is knowing where to look for things that you think someone else might have already solved. In this case I looked at the [binary search operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Binary_search_operations_.28on_sorted_ranges.29) reference, and know how to calculate an index from an iterator

Answer (score 1):

The lecture notes for the parallelized merge seems to be missing lines of pseudocode. This is my guess of a more complete example with the for loops parallelized:

```
for each a ∈ A do
    Do a binary search to find where a would be added into B
    C[rankA(a) + rankB(a)] = a
end
for each b ∈ B do
    Do a binary search to find where a would be added into B
    C[rankB(b) + rankA(b)] = b
end
```

There are some apparent issues with this approach. Assume there are 4 processors, with an initial array large enough that the average number of probes per binary search is 10. In this case, the binary search approach is slower, despite the parallelization. Since the searches are done in parallel, the order of the search instances is unknown, so each search instance searches all of B[] for RankB(a) or all of A[] for RankA(b). The parallelized writes to C[] may interfere with each other, since C[] is common to all processors.

A more common approach for n processors: split up the array into n parts, merge sort each of the n parts in parallel to create n sorted runs. Do n/2 parallel merges of even and odd pairs of the n sorted runs to create n/2 merged runs of twice the size. Do n/4 parallel merges of even and odd pairs of the n/2 merged runs to create n/4 merged runs ... . Do a final merge of two sorted runs to create a final sorted output.

---

A non-binary search explanation of rank:

```
rankA(a) is the index of a in A[]

rankB(b) is the index of b in B[]

// find rankB(a)
for(i = 0; i < size(B[]); i++)
    if(a <= B[i])break;          // <= for rankB(a)
rankB(a) = i;

// find rankA(b)
for(i = 0; i < size(A[]); i++)
    if(b < A[i])break;           // <  for rankA(b)
rankA(b) = i;
```

Comment: Can you gice an example how the rank function works for the two arrays [0,0,2,5,5,8] and [0,2,2,5,6,6] ?

Comment: @New2Math - I updated my answer to show simple example of rank, not using binary search.